# call php from ajax javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a PHP-based template website that has been heavily modified.

I am in the process of adding some RSS feeds, most of which are easy to "interpret" and display satisfactorily but one is in caps with "pre" formatting as well.

I want to modify the content. I look at all the mods I make as education and invariably am able to google satisfactory solutions to the problems I come across but, despite an earlier extensive programming background, without a thorough grounding in Javascript, Ajax, PHP, CSS and HTML, there are sometimes things that just frustrate the hell out of me.

All I want to do is pass a block of text from javascript code to PHP code, massage it and get the result back.
I am at a point in a ajax/jscript function where...

```
items[i].content
```

...contains the block of text that I want massaged and I have a piece of code that I got from here, I think, that ostensibly calls the PHP code...

```
function compute() {
    var params="session=123";
    $.post('wxspellch.php',params,function(data){ 
        alert(data);//for testing if data is being fetched
        var myObject = eval('(' + data + ')');
        document.getElementById("result").value=myObject(addend_1,addend_2);
    });
```

...and, unfortunately, it isn't documented so I don't have a clue what has to be customized. All I have done so far is enter the name of my PHP script.
The PHP script is written like this...

```
$pspell = pspell_new('en','american','','utf-8',PSPELL_FAST);
function spellCheckWord($word) {
    global $pspell;
    $autocorrect = TRUE;
    // Take the string match from preg_replace_callback's array
    $word = $word[0];
    etc......
}
function spellCheck($string) {
    return preg_replace_callback('/\b\w+\b/','spellCheckWord',$string);
}
echo spellCheck("...... the data   .......")
```

The PHP tests out fine with hard-coded data.
I just need to know what further customizing I have to do to the javascript and php in order to facilitate the passing and recovery of the block of text.

Comment: Check the jQuery docs about $.post, that IS documented.

Comment: Are you asking how in PHP to read the data that is POSTed?

Comment: checkout the [jquery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) document where you should do error handling incase it responds error during POST. the second point is making sure it set the content type to be JSON in your php like this: `header("Content-Type", "application/json")` so that you don't need to do `eval` which is a big security whole.